# how to download a publicly shared file from google drive in a browser using fetch and without using google authentication

Tags: fetch

I would like to fetch a file using javascript from a browser client for a file stored in google drive.

Assumptions:

1. User has set full access to the file.
2. The file is just a stored file like a json etc. not a google docs or google sheet file.
3. In my use-case, the user specifies the url in an input box and the javascript program should retrieve it.
4. The program is not just for google drive but for any internet accessible public storage (say S3 too).

Hence I wished to use `fetch(url)`.

When the download url is entered on a browser window (`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=<FILE_ID>`) it downloads the file. But when set inside fetch it gives a **Access to Fetch has been blocked due to CORS**. When I try to use the `{"mode": "no-cors"} in the fetch command it gives a response with type opaque.

Is there a generic way to download a file?

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. How much size do you want to download from Google Drive? 2. From `The program is not just for google drive but for any internet accessible public storage (say S3 too).`, in your situation, is it required to be able to use the same script for downloading the files from various site?

Comment: @Tanaike: the files would not be very large. ranging from a few KB to few hundreds of KB max. And the reason for having a common method (fetch API) is so that there is no cloud storage specific APIs w / wo credentials involved. To me its a simple case of someone willing to publicly share a file and being able to access that file from within a client browser program

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand about your situation. In the current stage, when you want to download the publicly shared file on Google Drive using `fetch` of Javascript, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns because of the issue in your question. 1. Use API key like `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?alt=media&key={APIKey}`. 2. Use Web Apps created by Google Apps Script as a wrapper for downloading. In this case, API key is not required. If those were not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. The first option will not suit my use-case. Let me check the documentation of the second option and update this post if found suitable.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About 2nd suggestion, if that was also not useful, I apologize.